# Can't do a simple redirect after POST request in Django (using HttpResponseRedirect)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to return an HTTP Response after a POST request in Django, it does not seem to be working. I have illustrated that below using HttpResponseRedirect.

When executing below code, I see the 'hello' message but it does not redirect. if I move the 'return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/')' line to the bottom then it does redirect upon loading the page, so the line does work otherwise.

```
if request.POST:
    print('hello')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thank-you/')
else:
    return render(request, 'account.html')
```

Answer (score 5):

You inspect the method by comparing [**`request.method`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method) with the method you want, so here `request.method == 'POST'`. [**`request.POST`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) is a `QueryDict` that contains the parameters in the POST request, but not every POST request has POST parameters. If such POST request has no parameters, then `if request.POST` will fail.

You thus can use:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    print('hello')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thank-you/')
else:
    return render(request, 'account.html')
```

That being said, you probably want to use [**`redirect(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) instead. `redirect(..)` is a shortcut in which you can specify the name of the view. If you later change the path of a view, then this will still work, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

if request.method == 'POST':
    print('hello')
    return redirect('name-of-view')
else:
    return render(request, 'account.html')
```

The `redirect(..)` will perform a "reverse lookup" and wrap the path that it generates into a `HttpResponseRedirect(..)` object. So in essence it is exactly the same, but this technique is more "stable" since as said, if you change your `urls.py`, the reverse lookup will still succeed.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the same results with using 'redirect' and checking whether the method is POST instead of checking for POST data.

Comment: @blitz: can you print `request.method` before the `if` statement, it really looks that you do not make a POST request in the first place. Does your log shows POST or GET (or PUT, PATCH, DELETE, etc.)?

Comment: @blitz: are you sure you trigger the correct view. In the code you posted, there is no `print('hi')`, so perhaps you trigger a different view.

Comment: Hi Willem, I can print the method indeed, I get:
POST
hello
in console (I've put hello before just to test if the method is POST and it only prints hello when I make the POST request so I think the check is good)

Comment: @blitz: you did not forget the `return` in `return Http...` or `return redirect(..)`?

Comment: Nope. If I move that exact same redirect line to the bottom of the view then it works and the redirect works upon refreshing the page. After the post request, I get the correct GET request in console immediately after, so it looks like it thinks that it is redirecting but it isn't:
[16/May/2019 09:42:05] "GET /thank-you/ HTTP/1.1" 200 53822

Answer (score 3):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    print('hello')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thank-you/')
else:
    return render(request, 'account.html')
```

well you need to check the method

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

if request.method == 'POST':
        print('hello')
        return redirect('/thank-you/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account.html')
```

thanks to @Willem Van Onsem for pointing POST needs to be a string and not a CONSTANT

Comment: I get the same results, i.e.:
- There is no redirect
- when POST request is made, I see 'Hi' printed in console, otherwise I don't
- I get 'GET /thank-you/ HTTP/1.1 200' in console which makes it look like it is trying to redirect but nothing actually happens in browser

Comment: @Exprator: I think the problem is that you used `POST` as an identifier, not as a string literal.

Comment: Same results, tried both solutions. In the console it seems to say that it is redirecting but I am getting nothing in the browser, stays on the same page.

Comment: do you have an url with that name that you are trying to redirect to?

Comment: Yes, and the view redirects to that URL if I initiate the redirect not via the POST request.