# How to redirect after add/edit/delete in django

Tags: python, django

when i try to redirect after add/edit/delete operation i'm redirecting to the page i wanted but can not see the existing data, but after click on url section of browser and tap enter on it or go to other page and return to this one than it is showing me the data.
Let me share a video link of deleting records. - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qyt_gxFoBe74DH_2rLbme9PD58Ll1z3I/view?usp=sharing

and
here is the code of deleting too.

views.py

```
def deleteuser(request, id):
    # user = get_object_or_404(AddContact, id = id)
    user = AddContact.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
    context = {
        'user' : user
    }
    return render (request, "adduser.html", context)
```

URL.py

```
path('deleteuser/<id>', views.deleteuser, name="deleteuser"),
```

html button

```
{% for vr in adduser.adduser.all %}
    <a href="/deleteuser/{{vr.id}}" class="btn btn-danger" data-target="success-modal-delete"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What `data` do you wish to see when you redirect? Is it that you want to display the `user` info which you've passed via the context dictionary when you've deleted it?

Comment: Why not using url tag in anchor tag as `href="{% url 'deleteuser' vr.id %}"`.

Comment: data is listed in table as you can see on the video.

Comment: See if the answer below works for you. @CaptionAmerica

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect to another url after sending a POST request to admin:auth\_user\_password\_change in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717093/how-to-redirect-to-another-url-after-sending-a-post-request-to-adminauth-user-p)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164972/cant-do-a-simple-redirect-after-post-request-in-django-using-httpresponseredir

Comment: @IvanStarostin no, it didn't work in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, even within that video... You're trying to view deleted data. You are clicking the delete button which removed all `instance` of the queryset returned by `id`, then basically returning `None`.

What you might want to do is after you delete the user, get a fresh queryset to the context dictionary with the remaining users. For example:

```
def deleteuser(request, id):
     d_user = get_object_or_404(AddContact, id=id)  # uncomment here...
     
     # if object returned then delete it
     if d_user:
          d_user.delete()

     # Retreiving the remaining users after deleting the above
     users = AddContact.objects.all()

     context = {
         'users' : users
     }
     return render (request, "adduser.html", context)
```

Ideally, that should work.

And as recommended, maybe you should use:

```
context = {
    'user' : user
}

<a href="{% url 'deleteuser' vr.id %}" class="btn btn-danger" data-target="success-modal-delete"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete</a>
```

Even though what you have still works.

**Updates**

Ensure the name of the `queryset` you're passing from here (*the delete view*) is the same as the one you're passing from the initial stage (*the add view*). So if in the `add view` you have passed:

```
context = {
    'contacts' : contacts  # -> the queryset name
}
return render (request, "adduser.html", context)
```

Ensure it's the same for the `delete view`:

```
context = {
    'contacts' : contacts  # -> the queryset name
}
return render (request, "adduser.html", context)
```

Comment: I've tried with this also but it remains the same in retrieving the data and the url in anchor tag both.

Comment: How are you iterating over the `queryset`? What name are you using? Example:  `{% for user in users %}...{% endfor %}`? Is the name you're using `users`? If that's the case then what you should return in the context dictionary is `'users' : users` .

Comment: You can check the updated portion of the answer. If that doesn't work, then maybe you should re-edit your question and add the `html` portion that contains the `for loop`.